# Error al correr Java Application: "non-existing project"

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy intentando correr mi proyecto en Eclipse Luna (jdk1.7.0), java application, en el que en el nombre del proyecto le puse `600343_BPM_GOPII` y cuando voy a correrlo me encuentro con el siguiente error:

> Launch configuration 1 references non-existing project
>   600343_BPM_GOPII.

No se porqué puede ser, si el proyecto existe.

Comment: Cómo lo corres? Clic derecho --> Run as --> Java application?

Comment: Exacto @Alfabravo

Comment: Al igual que las clases los nombres de proyectos no pueden empezar con números.